# xmllint selects a node even though contains() should not match

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I've got this CML input:

```
<prova>
    <parent>
        <groupId>error</groupId>
    </parent>
    <groupId>ok</groupId>
</prova>
```

and this XPath:

```
xmllint --xpath '/prova/parent/groupId/text()[contains(.,'ok')]'
```

that should not match anything but it matches `error`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use nested single quotes:

```
xmllint --xpath '/prova/parent/groupId/text()[contains(.,"ok")]' test.xml
```

result

```
XPath set is empty
```

**Explanation:**

The shell sees `'/prova/parent/groupId/text()[contains(.,'ok')]'` as

```
/prova/parent/groupId/text()[contains(.,ok)]
```

In this XPath, `ok` is interpreted as an element name. The element `<ok>` does not exist, so this selects an empty node-set.

For the sake of `contains()`, the empty node-set is converted to the empty string. And any string contains the empty string, so the condition is always true.

Comment: Thanks, a stupid error i get the answer myself probably when you were writing the answer. Anyway thanks

Comment: also see the explanation.